# Transformer Leakage Inductance and power factor

Tags: transformer, electric-machine, power-factor-correction, electrically-conductive

How does transformer         leakage impedance affect          power factor? Or how does the           X/R ratio of the     transformer change        the power factor ?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Please lookup the transformer *equivalent circuit* and see the three reactances Xp, Xs and Xm and how they contribute to the reactance seen by the source for different loads.

Comment: Do not flag questions as low quality unless they are spam or [a comment](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: What it means by low quality? Questions are effects of doubts and doubts are human beings naturally outcome and that outcome is a product of the nature.